# Trigger a rerender of parent component when a child component is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, rerender

I am using the following material-ui theme [Paperbase](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/premium-themes/paperbase) and within the `Header.js` component, I have the following `useEffect` hook:

```
const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState([]);

  const getTemperature= async () => {
    try {

      const response = await fetch('/get-temperature')
      const tempData = await response.json();

      setTemperature(tempData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
    getTemperature();
}, []);
```

The main purpose of this, is to display the current temperature as info, within the header component, which gets displayed at first page load/render.

Now within my App.js below, I have the following `return` setup where the above `Header` component is called.

```
return (
    <Router>
      <UserProvider myinfo={myinfo}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <div className={classes.root}>
                  <CssBaseline />
                  <nav className={classes.drawer}>
                    <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
                      <Navigator />
                    </Hidden>
                  </nav>
                  <div className={classes.app}>
                    <Header
                      onDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
                    />
                    <main className={classes.main}>
                      <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/new-user"
                          render={(props) => <Content key={props.location.key} />}
                        />
                        <Route exact path="/view-results"
                          render={(props) => <ViewResults key={props.location.key} />}
                        />
                      </Switch>
                    </main>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ThemeProvider>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </UserProvider>
    </Router>
);
```

My question is, how can I trigger a rerender of `Header` (parent) whenever the user routes to either `/new-user` or `/view-results` which in turn calls either `Content.js` or `ViewResults.js`, inorder to make the `useEffect` in Header.js refresh the data, from the REST api fetch and display the latest temperature in the header again?

Ideally anytime `Content.js` or `ViewResults.js` is rendered, ensure that Header.js `getTemperature()` is called.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have a problem of structuring your components and route. A <Router> should only contains <Route> and your Header should be inside route and be able to capture the path. What you need here is a layout implementation.

Comment: @ThanhTrung - I believe that was a typo. If still not correct, would appreciate your help inorder to solve my re-render issue.

Comment: Like I said, Header has to be a descendant of Route. Otherwise you need to put your useEffect inside Content and ViewResult. Then trigger a callback up to Router to pass on Header. Check this https://dev.to/selvaece25/multiple-layout-in-react-router-3acb

Comment: @ThanhTrung - please see updated <Router> setup where my <Header> is now a  descendant of Route. Unfortunately I am still unsure how to trigger a re-render of <Header> whenever the user enters `/new-user` or `/view-results`. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is pretty close to a multi layout system. As being a component child of `Route`, you can access the current location via `useLocation()` or even the native `window.location.pathname`.

This is my example of multi layout React app. You can try to use it to adapt to your code.

The `MainLayout` use a fallback route when no `path` is specified. It also contains a `Header` and include a page

```js
const Dispatcher = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    history.push('/home');

    return null;
};

const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route
                component={Dispatcher}
                exact
                path="/"
            />

            <Route
                exact
                path="/login/:path?"
            >
                <LoginLayout>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            component={LoginPage}
                            path="/login"
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </LoginLayout>
            </Route>

            <Route>
                <MainLayout>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            component={HomePage}
                            path="/home"
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </MainLayout>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

And here is the code for `MainLayout`

```js
const MainLayout = ({ children }) => (
    <Container
        disableGutters
        maxWidth={false}
    >
        <Header location={props.location} />

        <Container
            component="main"
            maxWidth={false}
            sx={styles.main}
        >
            {children}
        </Container>

        <Footer />
    </Container>
);
```

Now that `Header` can be anything. You need to put a capture in this component

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

cont Header = (props) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  
  //alternatively you can access props.location
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname === '/new-user') {
      getTemperature();
    }
  }, [pathname]);  
};
```

Note that Header is not a direct descendant of `Route` therefore it cannot access the location directly via `props`. You need to transfer in chain

```
Route -> MainLayout -> Header
```

Or better use `useLocation`